# How to group a set of records (i.e. into a invoice / billing cycle)

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, grouping, sql-server-2016

For a set of invoice stage records by project I'm trying to determine a billing cycle using the ID of the starting invoice stage.

Here's the table - `InvoiceStages`

```
|ID| Project | StageDate | InvoiceStage            | StageFlag | BillCycle |
|1 | abc123  | 10-May-18 | Finance                 |     S     |    1      |
|2 | abc123  | 15-May-18 | Review Draft            |           |    1      |
|4 | abc123  | 19-May-18 | Approved - NO Changes   |           |    1      |
|7 | abc123  | 21-May-18 | Final Invoice           |     E     |    1      |
|9 | abc123  | 05-Jun-18 | Finance                 |     S     |    9      |
|12| abc123  | 07-Jun-18 | Review Draft            |           |    9      |
|15| abc123  | 09-Jun-18 | Approved - With Changes |           |    9      |
|21| abc123  | 10-Jun-18 | Review Draft            |           |    9      |
|25| abc123  | 12-Jun-18 | Approved - NO Changes   |           |    9      |
|40| abc123  | 13-Jun-18 | Final Invoice           |     E     |    9      |
|3 | xyz789  | 15-May-18 | Finance                 |     S     |    3      |
|5 | xyz789  | 19-May-18 | Review Draft            |           |    3      |
|6 | xyz789  | 20-May-18 | Approved - NO Changes   |           |    3      |
|8 | xyz789  | 22-May-18 | Final Invoice           |     E     |    3      |
|10| xyz789  | 06-Jun-18 | Finance                 |     S     |    10     |
|11| xyz789  | 07-Jun-18 | Review Draft            |           |    10     |
|18| xyz789  | 09-Jun-18 | Approved - NO Changes   |           |    10     |
|22| xyz789  | 11-Jun-18 | Final Invoice           |     E     |    10     |
```

I've looked at LAG / LEAD but wasn't sure if that would be the best option.

```
Select
    ID
    , Project
    , StageDate
    , InvoiceStage
    , StageFlag
    , ?? As BillCycle
From InvoiceStages
```

I expect the output for BillCycle to be the ID of the first record where StageFlag = 'S' for all records up to and including the end stage 'E'. Then the next set will start with the ID starting with 'S' again.

Comment: Please add the tag of the database are you are using to the question (eg “oracle”)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a group using a cumulative sum and then use a window function to get the value:

```
select i.*,
       max(id) over (partition by project, grp) as invoice_id
from (select i.*,
             sum(case when i.stageflag = 'S' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by i.project order by i.stagedate) as grp
      from InvoiceStages i
     ) i;
```

If the ids increase along with the date, you can do this without a subquery:

```
select i.*,
       max(case when stageflag = 'S' then id end) over (partition by project) as invoice_id
from invoicestages i;
```

Comment: I used the first query as the second one was missing the grp field as that was in the subquery.  Thanks for answering my question so quickly Gordon!